# Ошибка OverflowError: int too large to convert to float стараюсь найти факториал милиона формула выведена из формулыс стирлинга

Tags: python

```
import math
n=1000000
f=math.sqrt(157*n)
print(n**500*f*n**n/5000000*1359**n)
```

Comment: а что вы хотели. возведение в степень целочисленное. понятно что там ничего во флоат не влезет.

Comment: Формула очень странная, там точно скобок нигде не должно быть?? Да, и вы представляете, сколько знаков будет у факториала из миллиона?! Куда вы их выводить собрались, никаких экранов не хватит на это ))

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что значение, которое вы вычисляете, слишком большое для того, чтобы быть представленным в виде числа с плавающей точкой. Лучше здесь применить цикл или рекурсию, вместо того, чтобы использовать матем. формулы.
Ещё можно попробовать библиотеки `decimal` или `bigfloat` для вычисления факториала.
Или  библиотеку numpy, которая имеет функцию factorial.

```
n = 1000000
result = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    result *= i
print(result)
```

или так

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

n = 1000000
print(factorial(n))
```

Ещё можно решить через math

```
import math
n = 1000000
print(math.gamma(n+1))
```

Отмечу, что результат лучше сохранять в файл чтобы не тратить много памяти.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы запустили второй код, чтобы его проверить